# How to safely distantly remove a usb hard drive in Debian using terminal

Tags: usb, debian, external-hard-drive, unmount

I'm connected via ssh to a Debian computer. What I need to to do is to safely remove the external usb storage device.

I have found [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/35508/eject-usb-drives-eject-command/384075#384075?newreg=a6bbf6a6cdc046c88652605846ef896a) answer to a comparable question. One of the recommendations is just to eject or unmount by doing `sudo eject /dev/sda`. Now my problem is that I don't have a /dev/sd*.
So the next proposed solution is by  echo

```
'offline' > /sys/block/sdb/device/state
echo '1' > /sys/block/sdb/device/delete
```

Now my problem is another one. How do I now the my usb hard drive is sdb and not sda, sdc or sdd?

```
lsusb `just shows me` Bus 002 Device 008: ID 1058:25a2 Western Digital Technologies, Inc. Elements 25A2
```

Do you have any ideas?
Thanks in advance

Comment: check `lsblk` -output.

Comment: this is for root only :(

Comment: `$ lsblk` -> `NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT`, `sda      8:0    0 232,9G  0 disk `,   `├─sda4   8:4    0  30,5G  0 part [SWAP]`, ....  i.e. no sudo. Ubuntu 16.04 (debian based)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're doing is too compilcated. ;-)

Usually it suffices to do the following:

1. `umount` the mounted media (if the device has multiple partitions then do that for all of them).
2. Execute `eject /dev/sdN` (or whatever `/dev/disk/by-id/...` is more useful for you; or a device from another hierarchy under `/dev/disk`).

You might intersperse a call to `sync` between those two but I'd say it's for truly paranoid persons as `eject` should take care of forcing the kernel to push any buffered data to the device. See [`eject(1)`](https://manpages.debian.org/1/eject).

Comment: Oh, I've misread your question. So the only useful portion of it is to check out the hierarchy under `/dev/disk`. Also you can run `dmesg` as root and see what device node was assigned to your drive when it was plugged in.

Answer (score 0):

These worked for my debian11 system:

To unmount:

udisksctl unmount   --block-device /dev/sdb1

To Power off (ie safely remove) the device:

udisksctl power-off --block-device /dev/sdb